# python memory leak using open cv in threads

Tags: python, multithreading, opencv, memory-leaks

I have this piece of code that leaks a bit of memory with every iteration, however I cannot really understand why.

ran into this because I have a piece of code that occasionally takes images and saves them to disk using opencv, I do this in a thread in order to not slow down the program while the images are being saved but eventually the computer freezes because it has reached memory capacity. This seems to come up sometimes when calling opencv functions in a thread like this:

```
import threading
import cv2
import numpy as np
import gc

class Memleak_test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.thread = None

    def test(self, frame):
        frame = cv2.resize(frame, (20, 20))
        
    def run_threaded(self):
        frame = np.zeros((10, 10, 3)).astype(np.uint8)
        self.thread = threading.Thread(target=self.test, args=(frame,))
        self.thread.start()

    def test_memleak(self):
        if self.thread is not None:
            self.thread.join()
        self.run_threaded() # leaks memory
        return None

m = Memleak_test()
while True:

    m.test_memleak()
    gc.collect()
```

reading around seems to point to something called *thread-local storage (TLS)* and has supposedly been fixed in opencv 3.4 https://github.com/LumiGuide/haskell-opencv/issues/109 but I'm experiencing this in a newer version. Is there a way for me to prevent the memory from leaking? or will I have to change my code such that only ever a single thread is spawned and then that single thread runs queue-d tasks or will that also cause a leak?

Comment: I can reproduce this (I'm on windows). it grows slowly but steadily. the code without threading behaves well. the threading without opencv calls behaves well too. this must be some interaction between opencv and python's threading, and it's proportional to the *total number of thread creations*. you should file a bug on opencv's github.

Comment: It does not occur without the resize() call. But it also occurs without parameter passing when you create `frame` inside `test()` and resize.

Comment: it is not limited to the resize function, it seems to happen with any piece of code where opencv returns a value for example `cv2.GaussianBlur(frame, (3, 3), 3)` and `cv2.applyColorMap(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)` but not `cv2.line(frame, (1,1),(1,2),(255,0,0),3)`

Comment: all of those return "a value" but the line function returns what you passed it (not a new matrix). I'd say the first two cause an opencl context to be created. the third one does not.

Comment: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/5150 in this issue, they propose to build OpenCV from code with a different library for the thread pool, have you tried that?
Basically just adding  "-D BUILD_TBB=ON -D WITH_TBB=ON" when building

Comment: No I ended up just ensuring that I reuse the thread instead of spawning a new one each time. I made an issue on the opencv github repo https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/23912#event-9717722557 I got some answers there but never ended up using them.